# Passenger Errors in Ruby 1.9.3 Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, compatibility, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to set up my *Rails* app on *Apache*.
I am using Passenger to load my *Rails App*. It seems like *Passenger* does not support the new Ruby hash format `x: y` but supports the old one `:x => y`. The Ruby version I am using is `1.9.3`

This is the error message I get:

```
categories_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.json { render json: @categories }
categories_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.json { render json: @category }
categories_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.json { render json: @category }
categories_controller.rb:50: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ...redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully cr...
categories_controller.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ... format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, ...
categories_controller.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '=' ...ender json: @category, status: :created, location: @category... 
categories_controller.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.html { render action: "new" }
categories_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ... format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :un...
categories_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '=' ...son: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
categories_controller.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ...redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully up...
categories_controller.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.html { render action: "edit" }
categories_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' ... format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :un...
categories_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '=' ...son: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

Is there any work around for this . I don't want to convert all hashes to :x => y format.

Comment: What makes you think Passenger is using Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: Because when I change the hash format to :x => y it works . This happens when I used ruby 1.8.7. But using 1.9.3 , the hash format is of the form :x y. So my only guess is because of the ruby version .

Comment: So apparently Passenger is using 1.8 but you need it to use 1.9.3. Again, why would you think Passenger would be using 1.9 when it clearly isn't using 1.9.

Comment: I guess it because my PassengerRoot is pointing to user/lib/ruby1.8 . So its not recognizing ruby 1.9 syantax . I will try downloading ruby1.9 gems ..

Answer (score 1):

I think your passenger is using Ruby 1.8.x.

switch you passenger to version 3.2, to make sure that you are using 1.9.3 for this rails app.

refer to: https://serverfault.com/a/388821

Comment: Is there a installation instruction for passenger 3.2 anywhere ?